# Sqlite database Protection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite, xcode4.3

I am devloping an application which stores a huge amount of data in the sqlite database. But I want to keep the data safe so that no one hacks my database and see the data in my database.

Now how can I encrypt and decrypt my sqlite database?

Pls help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was developed an app that require and I've used this way

First of all, I've initiated a class, called it `ConstantMethods.h+m`

ConstantMethods.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

static NSString *keyEncryption = @"YourPrivateKey";
@interface ConstantMethods : NSObject {

}
+ (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key;
+ (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key;

@end
```

ConstantMethods.m

```
#import "ConstantMethods.h"

@implementation NSData (AES256)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end

@implementation ConstantMethods

+ (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}

+ (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Then, in your class, import the `ConstantMethods.h` and use the class as the following:

```
[ConstantMethods encryptString:@"yourString"];
```

and when you want to decrypt, use the following:

```
[ConstantMethods decryptData:@"yourString" withKey:keyEncryption];
```

After the encryption, insert the encrypted data to the database, and when retrieving the data from database, decrypt it.

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response.
 i just got a doubt im doing it this way like im converting nsdata to nsstring
NSData *test = [ConstantMethods encryptString:InsertName withKey:keyEncryption];
    NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[test bytes]];

 
 sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [newStr UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

Comment: by the way, why do you use SQLite, use Core Data, it's more friendly and readable and if you like and see my answer is useful for you, don't forget to vote up and mark it as a correct answer, thank you.

Comment: Hey scar im able to encrypt the data but when i decrypt the data it returns me nil value..

Comment: the encrypted string on decrypting is returning an empty string its like "" in this way.

Comment: I guess that the encryption wasn't right, please check out what you did, edit your post and add some code that you use to help you.

Comment: @Scar, Is it possible, that this method doesnt work like that anymore in ios6? Have a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596280/cccrypt-difference-between-ios5-and-ios6

Comment: @Andy let me check it out, i will come back with answer that fit iOS 6