# CCCrypt difference between iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, encryption, ios6

I have got a decryption/encryption method using `CCCrypt()` which worked really well on iOS5. Now I am working with the iOS6 SDK and never changed my code, but it seems that something is broken. I can still encrypt a string with a key and decrypt it, but if I use another key to decrypt the same string, the `CCCryptStatus` coming back from `CCCrypt()` is still `0(kCCSuccess)` - even when the decryption fails, because after that my NSData isn't filled. On iOS5 I got the error message -4303 which I could handle then. Any ideas what can be wrong now?

My Code:

```
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; 
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
{
    data = [GTMBase64 decodeData:data];
}

NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;

void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr,
                                      kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL ,
                                      [data bytes], dataLength, 
                                      buffer,       bufferSize, 
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus != kCCSuccess){
    // do something, but cryptStatus is always 0!
}
```

EDIT:
Tested it on iPad Simulator 5. When I make a decryption with another key the status I receive is -4303. Only in ios6 the status coming back is 0.

Comment: I seem to have similar problem. Decryption is working in ios5 but fails in ios6. The encryption is done using mcrypt_encrypt in php. I also get success status but decryptedBytes are 0. Any ideas, solutions?

Comment: Im still searching for a solution. In the apple developer forum there is a thread called CommonCrypto issue. Some people discussed similiar problems but it did not help me until now to fix that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert i encryption, but I have the same problem and figured a workaround maybe it will be fine until some will find a real solution.

all I did is to figure which iOS is running and for 6+ i'm changing the CCCrypt call to no padding (0 is for no padding, 1 is the enum for kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

```
float version = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if (version >= 6)
{
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize, 
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );


    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); 
    return nil;
}
else
{
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 1,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize, 
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer );
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I did not test that already, but is it really only the padding which changed on iOS6? In the developer forum someone told me that my code is also not good for iOS5. But I do not know why...I think what I missed is the fact, that it is not possible to know if the decryption with another key failed - on iOS5 I got everytime a -4303 error if the decryption with another key failed. But that was probably lucky...So my real problem is perhaps the whole idea, not the code for iOS6.

Comment: We had some issues with this and it adding trailing bytes on the end of the encryption and / or the decryption. Setting 0 padding fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an apple [developer forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/157474?tstart=0) discussing this issue and it has a good amount of info on the topic. It seems that the padding option is an issue for many people. Comment #11 is where the solution starts to be discussed.